# JSF 1.2 DataTable Bestway Remove Row

Tags: jsf, jsf-1.2, ajax4jsf

### JSF 1.2  DataTable

I know how to remove the row from datatable writing following code.

jsp

```
<h:graphicImage id="deleteRowBtn_img" url="../../images/table_icon_delete.gif" style="cursor:pointer" alt="Delete Row">
    <a4j:support id="deleteRowBtn" event="onclick"  actionListener="#{mnpAction.deleteMultiNoPortRow}" reRender="multiNoPortTable" oncomplete="resetViewConfigs();"/>
</h:graphicImage>
```

action bean

```
public void deleteMultiNoPortRow(ActionEvent ae) {
    {
        int index = abcBean.getDataTable().getRowIndex();
        mnpBean.getMultiNoPortingList().remove(index);
    }
}
```

But i want to know is there any other way to remove row from datatable in `JSF1.2`.
Any help regarding this appreciate!!!!!!

Comment: remove the item from the list in the backing bean of your `<h:dataTable>` or `<rich:dataTable>` and rerender (update) your table after the action.

Comment: @prageeth thanks for reply.How i identify particular object remove from list in backing bean??

Comment: It was me, not prageeth. Look for a tutorial on JSF DataTable like [Using datatables](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2006/06/using-datatables.html) from BalusC. Next time, please come with a specific question instead of *how can I do the foo that can be answered by googling*?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the same appearance and functionality by using an `a4j:commandButton` and its `image` attribute instead of `<h:graphicImage>` as below.

```
<a4j:commandButton image="../../images/table_icon_delete.gif" actionListener="#{mnpAction.deleteMultiNoPortRow}"/>
```

If your `<h:graphicImage>` is in a column of the table, you can pass the `var` of the table to a method in your baking bean and remove that element from the list without having to use the `row index`. Here use `action` instead of `actionListener`.

```
<a4j:support id="deleteRowBtn" event="onclick" action="#{mnpAction.remove(myVar)}".../>
```

In `mnpAction` bean (Assuming the type of your list is `T`)

```
public void remove(T s) {
   mnpBean.getMultiNoPortingList().remove(s);
}
```

Edit:
Since you are using JSF1.2 you may not use `#{mnpAction.remove(myVar)}"` to pass parameters to the `bean` if you don't like to upgrade your EL library.

Comment: The question is for JSF 1.2. Please tell OP that he/she must upgrade the EL library in order to send parameters through the action method call.

Comment: Indeed, the JSF 1.2 way would be to pass a paratemer to the commandButton or commandLink (h or a4j) using `<f:param>` or `<a4j:param>`. You should check the link posted in my comment on OP's question about working with datatables, by BalusC.